# javascript is reading coming null date as 1/1/1970

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using AngularJS calling a web API to store data, the problem is that JavaScript is reading `null` date as `1/1/1970` in input box.
How to make input box empty when coming date is `null`?

when reading data

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="title_lable">Date Of Certificate:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="cdate">
</div>
```

when displaying data in html table

```
 <tbody>
   <tr  ng-repeat="d in lifeSupportsdata" ng-click="showInEdit(d)"  ng-class="{selected:d=== selectedRow}">
     <td>{{d.Life}}</td>
     <td>{{d.Date_Issue | date :  "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
      <td>{{d.Date_Expiry | date :  "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
```

Angular Controller

```
$scope.showInEdit = function (member) {
  console.log(member);
  $scope.selectedRow = member;
  $scope.syskey = member.Sys_Key;
  $scope.life = '' + member.Life_Key + '';
  $scope.cdate = new Date(member.Date_Issue);
  $scope.edate = new Date(member.Date_Expiry);
```

any help or idea, how to display empty input box instead `1/1/1970`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello! It would be nice if you could include a [mcve] instead of those little code snippets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (member.Date_Expiry == null) {
        $scope.edate = '';
} else $scope.edate = new Date(member.Date_Expiry);
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation for the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="title_lable">Date Of Certificate:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" 
  ng-model="(cdate == null || cdate == '1/1/1970') ? '' : cdate">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but there is a green line error says"missing attribute name".

Comment: @Hassan It's because of the `""` there. You can change them to `''` but I suspect this is not the correct solution because it will not allow for two-way binding.

Comment: Maybe green error is not that bad.. How can the green be evil?

Comment: @JLRishe tanx for comment, change " to '

Comment: Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'cdate == null || cdate == '1/1/1970' ? '': cdate' is non-assignable. Element: <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine

Comment: @Hassan : Now test with parentheses

Comment: the last error is shown when i used the parentheses, any help

Comment: any help or idea

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made

Comment: kindly can you tell me what i am missing to write it?, thanks lot